# How could one implement "categories" in a CppUnit test suite?

Tags: cppunit

Closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717181/is-there-a-cppunit-equivalent-to-nunits-category-attribute-for-test-cases), I would like to be able to select tests to execute in a CppUnit assembly based on command-line arguments. Think `--exclude=integration,smoke,x64only` or `--include=unit`. [NUnit Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) work like this. **How can I implement something like that in CppUnit?**

I tried going down the route of adding an abstract base class `IHasCategories` with a method `get_Categories()`, and my test fixtures override the method to return a comma-separated list of categories. However, when we retrieve tests from CppUnit with a call like `CppUnit::Test *topLevelTest = CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest();`, we get an instance of `CppUnit::Test`. **What I really need here, and can't get to, is an instance of `CppUnit::TestFixture` to get my list of categories to check for.**

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be simple when you know the answer, so here it is for any future readers.

As I mentioned in the question, I've written an abstract base class `IHasCategories` with a method `get_Categories()`, and my test fixtures override the method to return a comma-separated list of categories.

The missing part of the puzzle was how to get the instances of `CppUnit::TestFixture` out of CppUnit. Turns out, CppUnit gives you a hierarchy of `CppUnit::Test` objects, and you can simply `dynamic_cast` these objects to the class you want.

The following code is a little specific to my needs, but may be helpful. This method provides a list of the objects in the hierarchy that represent, hierarchically, the TestFixtures. It's the objects in this list that I execute with a command like `test->run(&controller);`. When I want to examine an actual TestFixture object for categories, it will be the children of these objects that I want to dynamic_cast to an `IHasCategories`.

```
/**
 * Get TestSuite objects from the CppUnit hierarchy, that have, as their children,
 * TestFixture objects.
 */
void GetTestSuitesWithFixtures(const CppUnit::Test * test, std::vector<CppUnit::Test*> & suites)
{
    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < test->getChildTestCount(); ++childIndex)
    {
        CppUnit::Test * child = test->getChildTestAt(childIndex);

        CppUnit::TestSuite * testSuite = dynamic_cast<CppUnit::TestSuite*>(child);

        if (testSuite 
            && testSuite->getChildTestCount() > 0
            && dynamic_cast<CppUnit::TestFixture*>(testSuite->getChildTestAt(0)))
        {
            suites.push_back(testSuite);
        }
        else GetTestSuitesWithFixtures(child, suites);
    }
}
```